# NetApp & S3 put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration with a JSON file return all time MalformedXML

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, netapp

We have a problem on our StorageGrid with S3 Bucket !
When we try to put a Lifecycle Configuration on a S3 we all time have the same error :

`An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration operation: Invalid XML node or node is at wrong location.`

Sometimes, when JSON file is not good, we have an error and he try to help us like this :
`Error parsing parameter '--lifecycle-configuration': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 17 (char 30) JSON received:`

But, when we clear the JSON file and try to put a Licecycle Configuration we all time have the same error :
`An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration operation: Invalid XML node or node is at wrong location.`

I have searched and searched, but I haven't found an answer that solves my probem...

The JSON file in question can be found below:

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "ID": "rule1",
            "Expiration": {
                "ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker": true
            },
            "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
                "NewerNoncurrentVersions": 10,
                "NoncurrentDays": 30
            },
            "Status": "Enabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

If someone have a issue or an idea to solve my problem you are welcome !!!